# azure cognitive search migration to other product?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We have some products that heavily rely on azure cognitive search, it is a good product, but gradually we got quite a lot of problems with it, including:

1. You can't scale up or scale down without deleting the whole instance.
2. You can't use pipeline to create/update indexes unless you call it using web api. Modifying/delete field in an index is also not straightforward.
3. No data replication between search instances.
4. No cross index query even in the same instance.
5. No case insensitive search

Suggestions for above have been sitting in Microsoft's suggestion site for years and nothing was every done to address it. I really have no idea when or ever Microsoft will bother to provide better service.

As a result, I am starting to look around for alternative products (looking at elastic search at the moment). Is there any product that supports search syntax translation that make the migration easier (so we don't have to break so many things)?